# Cross Compiling Rust to OpenWRT fails with multiple candidates

Tags: cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I am having the below error when trying to cross compile a hello world using a custom toolkit.

```
Compiling libc v0.2.152
error[E0464]: multiple candidates for `rmeta` dependency `core` found 
= note: candidate #1: /<snip>/hello-rust/target/mipsel-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libcore-73f09c50a433633b.rmeta 
= note: candidate #2: /<snip>/hello-rust/target/mipsel-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librustc_std_workspace_core-d1a4ae30c7f1614c.rmeta
```

I am on OSX and trying to compile for a MIPSEL-unknown-linux-musl target. I have the toolchain setup but can't get the STD libraries to complie properly.

My build command is "cargo build -Zbuild-std=std,core,alloc -Zbuild-std-features=compiler-builtins-mem --target=mipsel-unknown-linux-musl --release"

Is there a way to specify which rmeta to use, or a way that it will automagically default to the first for instance.